# Best way to create inventory icons from your models?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I want to create inventory icons from my 3d models for the game I'm making. What's the best way to create such images? I essentially just want flat, consistent lighting. I'm not sure if there's a quick way to do that, though. Is there a way to do it without messing around with point lights, etc?

Any help is appreciated.